# R: forecast: finding the accuracy of arfima and nnetar forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to find the accuracy of an arfima and a nnetar forecast using the forecast package.  However I get an error message.

```
library(forecast)
library(fracdiff)
x <- fracdiff.sim( 100, ma=-.4, d=.3)$series 
fit <- arfima(x)
accuracy(fit)

Error in accuracy(fit) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.

fit <-nnetar(x)
accuracy(fit)

Error in accuracy(fit) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.
```

I would be grateful for your help in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: it works with `accuracy(forecast(fit))`

Comment: Please compare `class(fit)` and the error message.

Comment: Thanks very much.accuracy(forecast(fit)) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the forecast syntax eg

```
forecast(fit)
```

Then

```
accuracy(forecast(fit), x, test=NULL, d=NULL, D=NULL)
```